# what does the result do not make sense?

Tags: c++

I have programmed a small program to find the cos of any number
bur the result was all strange
the cmd :

> type the number 0.00
>
> effincisy5
>
> your cos =008C129E
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float cos67 (float l,float j)
{
    int k=0;
    float sum=0,i=1;
    while (k<=j)
    {
        sum +=i;
        i*=(-l*l/((2*l)*(2*l-1)));
        k+=1;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main(){
    float l,j;
    cout<<"type the number ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<endl<<"effincisy" ;
    cin>>j;
    cout<<endl;
    cos67(l,j);
    cout<<"your cos ="<<cos67<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

so why the result have letters on the number?

or what does it mean?

Comment: Typo; `cout<<"your cos ="<<cos67<<endl;` needs to be `cout<<"your cos ="<<cos67(l,j)<<endl;` and you can get rid of the `cos67(l,j);` that is on its own line.

Comment: Because you're printing the address of the function instead of its result...

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the address of the function and not the return value. Use:

```
cout<<"your cos ="<< cos67(l, j) <<endl;
```

Instead.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
 cout<<"your cos ="<<cos67<<endl;
```

is taking the address of the function and displaying it. You want the value the function returns:

```
 cout<<"your cos ="<< cos67(l,j) <<endl;
```